# Why isn't my custom iPhone delegate working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I'm just trying to build a simple delegate, it compiles successfully but it doesn't seem to do anything right now.
Please review my code below, both FirstViewContoller and SecondViewController have separate xib files, the SecondViewController has a button hooked up to the myMethod of course.

I've been learning my way around objective c and iPhone SDK for a couple of months, I've been using a book and lynda.com tutorial to aid, I actually copied most of the code using the xcode template for a utility app, and I believe I understand what is going on here, but is there something I've missed, as the button isn't responding.

If you need more info please ask.

Many thanks,
Chris

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate;


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


-(IBAction) myMethod;

@end

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate

-(void)viewControllerDidFinish:(SecondViewController *)controller;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate;

-(IBAction) myMethod
{
    [self.delegate viewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
//
@end
```

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>{
//
@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
@implementation FirstViewController

-(void)viewControllerDidFinish:(SecondViewControllerDelegate *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"delegate is being used");
}
//
@end
```

**Edit** - This is an old post but just to clarify I simply forgot to assign the SecondViewController delegate in the FirstViewController

Comment: I don't see you assigning the delegate property of SecondViewController, you must be doing that at creation? Sending a message to nil is legal...

Comment: Can you give me an example? This may be what is missing

Comment: Ok I got it, many many thanks.  It makes sense to assign the delegate property, I overlooked this part when viewing the Utility template as I wasn't doing any flip side view work.  I now understand that declaring the delegate isn't enough, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you assign the delegate property of SecondViewController?
This is the last part I am missing...

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Your IBAction method `myMethod`, if it really is an IBAction, needs to take an argument:
   `-(IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender`
   Before you blame the delegate pattern, make sure that myMethod is being called (set a breakpoint and see).
2. Your delegate method seems to be declared to take a delegate type as a param, not a viewController which is what you seem to want to be passing there. That might all get obscured by the id types, but I think you probably want to rejigger the declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben, it hasn't helped though
1 - If I try to add a sender argument to an IBaction method I get an error in IB and the app crashes
2 - That was a typo when transferring the code to this question, I've amended the above and that won't have been the case.

Is there anything else it could be?

Comment: Thanks again Ben, please ignore as Adam's suggestion helped.  Thanks for pointing out my mess though!

Comment: for the record, - (IBAction)respondToButtonClick;
- (IBAction)respondToButtonClick:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)respondToButtonClick:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event;

Are all valid IBActions, according to http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/CodeIntegration/CodeIntegration.html

If you change the type of the IBAction, I think you have to re-wire the connection in IB otherwise it'll try to send the wrong selector

Comment: Cool, glad it's working. I was assuming that in the uncopied snippets you were setting the delegate. :)

Comment: Ah, I will give that a shot, I'm not by my computer right now, but the error message on IB did say the action is no longer available, so I suppose re-wiring does make sense, still getting used to developing on mac but it's nice when I know what I'm doing! Thanks again